# 3-way merge in Visual SourceSafe using external tool

Tags: version-control, merge, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

I have WinMerge set up as my diff tool for VSS 2005. However WinMerge [doesn't support 3-way merge](http://manual.winmerge.org/Faq.html) (see #1.4). The docs for VSS say that 3-way merge IS supported in VSS:

> [if Visual SourceSafe detects that two of you have both modified the same piece of a file, a three-way merge technique must be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8hk7e2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I'd like recommendations on a good (free) tool I can use which will retain the ability to do 3-way merge, and is better than VSS' own merge/diff tool.

**I need to know how to integrate this with VSS, so VSS calls it when diff/merge operations are called.**

[image]

Comment: Did KDiff3 work for you, or, did you find something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend KDiff3:

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

***Others***

Meld is typically used with Git on Linux, and, there's a Windows version:

https://live.gnome.org/Meld/Windows

I haven't used it in a while, but, I think many Windows people would recommend p4Merge

http://www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list#ntx86

Comment: I can't offhand find how to integrate kdiff3 with VSS, any ideas? I know VSS passes 4 commands to a merge tool but not what they actually mean!

Comment: @John: your screenshot indicates what they actually mean...  See the "command line parameters" section at the bottom...  For kdiff3, you probably want `%3 %2 %1 -o %4`.  Flip `%1` and `%2` depending on whether you prefer ours on the left or right.

Comment: You can also match up @EdwardThomson comment with info from the kdiff3 README: https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/kdiff3/src/a007f2371e51/kdiff3/README (near the bottom of the file)